# Simple user input program doesn't allow time to input a key

Tags: java, input

I'm using Herbert Schildt's "A Beginner's Guide" book to learn. I'm currently on the section where I am to use `System.in.read()` to get user input.

When I run the program in the command prompt, only the `System.out.print` information is displayed and the command prompt immediately resets, not allowing me time to input a key.

```
class Guess {
 public static void main(String args[])
 throws java.io.IOException {

 char ch, answer = 'K';

 System.out.println("I'm thinking of a letter between a and z, guess it.");

 ch = (char) System.in.read(); // read a char from the keyboard

 if(ch == answer) System.out.println("Right");
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't have very good experience of the Windows command prompt. You could try running your program in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) instead. Eclipse is also a very good environment with lots of helpful tools for both writing and maintaining Java code, such as automatic management of imports, in-line compiler errors and warnings directly in the code, and much more.

Comment: Yea I plan to use an IDE eventually, is Netbeans also a good one?

Comment: I haven't really used Netbeans myself, but I've heard others say it's good.

Comment: I Executed your code as it is without any change on my Windows Command Prompt, and it executed fine... When i entered K, i got Right as the output and when i enter any other character i don't get any response as there is no else part to the if condition.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. I wonder if it's something to do with my personal laptop settings. When I execute it, my command prompt immediately resets to C:\directory and gives me no time whatsoever to enter a key. I wonder I wonder...

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code is working properly. The only problem is that the program will automatically terminated if the user will input the character'K' because it is the end of the program. It terminates the program too fast ,too fast for you to see the "Right" output.